# Mopub Unity Android crashing on startup

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, mopub

I am trying to integrate Mopub for Android into my Unity project. I've followed the instructions here:

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-unity-android-plugin

building the mopub sdk with Android support and then adding it to my unity project. I've added the appropriate entries to my AndroidManifest.xml as so:

```
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
<activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
<activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
<activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

...

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The project builds fine, but when I run it on the device I am getting a crash the moment I request an interstitial or a banner ad. Here's the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15901): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
E/AndroidRuntime(15901): Unity version     : 4.6.1f1
E/AndroidRuntime(15901): Device model      : samsung GT-I9300
E/AndroidRuntime(15901): Device fingerprint: samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XXUGNH4:user/release-keys
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):
E/AndroidRuntime(15901): Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    NonNull cannot be resolved to a type
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at com.mopub.common.util.ManifestUtils.checkWebViewActivitiesDeclared(ManifestUtils.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:64)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubUnityPlugin$1.run(MoPubUnityPlugin.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
E/AndroidRuntime(15901):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/ActivityManager( 2344): Notify an ApplicationCrash
```

I've tried the sample Unity scene that ships with the mopub Unity plugin, and the exact same thing is happening. Looking at checkWebViewActivitiesDeclared [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sdk/src/main/java/com/mopub/common/util/ManifestUtils.java) gives me some clues that my activities may be wrong, but I can't see what error I'm making.

Comment: You might get better response posting to Android SE

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Android, but there is a line said:

> NonNull cannot be resolved to a type

So, it maybe the source of the crash.

<del>Have you try importing: `android-support-annotations.jar` ?</del>

Try importing `android-support-annotations.jar` . It should resolve NonNull .